# how to make text scrollable inside button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I declared a button in android dynamically with some width and height as wrap_content.
I want the text to be scrollable inside the button rather than adjusting to down which increases the height of button. Can anyone help in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Code sample :

```
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            110,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Button  newButton = new Button(ctx);
    newButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    newButton.setText("some nameeeeeeeeeeeee");
            newButton.setScroller(new Scroller(getActivity())); 
    newButton.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
    newButton.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Button btn = new Button(context);
btn.setScroller(new Scroller(context)); 
btn.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
btn.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Hope it must helps! :)

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    110,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                Button  newButton = new Button(ctx);
  newButton.setLayoutParams(params);
  newButton.setText(lableName);
                newButton.setScroller(new Scroller(getActivity())); 
  newButton.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
  newButton.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Comment: The above is the way in which my code is written. The text comes down as  when it exceeeds the width of button.

Answer (score 0):

this property can be used to scroll the text Horizontally:

```
android:scrollHorizontally
```

Comment: I did the same , but the text is not scrolling.Only part of Text is visible , remaining part is not scrollable